# Error- Failed to launch debuggee in terminal. Reason: com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException

Tags: visual-studio-code, eclipse-temurin

Recently vs code gives me this error when i try to run any java program. I've searched for solutions online but none seemed to work. (The jdk i use is Eclipse Adoptium)

[Error Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ4u1.png)
[Error Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNSc9.png)

I thought it could be the jdk so i uninstalled and reinstalled it along with vs code but it didnt do anything. The solutions online seemed to vary from person to person too